# rails link_to category that has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Pages that belongs_to Category 
for the Pages I have controller and model
for the Category I only have model and I made a relations between them

on my PagesContoller I have:

```
@categories = Category.all
```

and this is how I show it on my page:

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
  <%= cat.name %>
  <%= link_to "category", ????? %>
<% end %>
```

Now I'm trying to create a link that will go to each Category, any ideas?

Comment: paste your PagesContoller @user4571629

Answer (score 1):

```
 <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
      <%= cat.name %>
      <%= link_to "category", category_path(cat) %>
    <% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

First of all you should have categories controller I don't find any reason why you wont do it. Secondly if you wanna handle every thing in pages controller then add a route and action in pages controller. like in your route file

```
get 'pages/categories/:id' => "pages#category" , :as=>:category
```

then In `pages_controller` add an action named `category`

```
def category
@category=Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: but I don't have category_path, as I said I only created model for category

Comment: I don't see any change on your answer

Comment: I guess I have to create Controller for Categories

Comment: Yes you should . You should treat Category as Resource so all of the Category CRUD operation should be handled in categories controller

Comment: After I click on the link I see the show.html.erb, Do you have any idea how can show the pages that are only in this category?